# Dark color scheme for visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, themes, color-scheme

on my fresh installation of `VS 2012`, i was working on changing default color & theme settings..

for that, i followed the below steps

- installed [theme gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/366ad100-0003-4c9a-81a8-337d4e7ace05)
- used `dark with light`
- then imported [Railscast](http://tom.net.nz/2010/07/visual-studio-2010-theme/) color scheme from [here](http://tom.net.nz/uploads/private/Railscast-VisualStudio2010.vssettings)

but after i applied the color scheme some keywords won't get the scheme's color
[on the first loading of vs, after a fraction of second it changes]
the reason i guess, vs might be overriding the custom scheme's color.

i had this overriding phenomenon in VS 2010, at that time i had installed `Visual Assist`, and it was overriding the custom color scheme, in that case i reduced the coloring in Visual Assist, (under visual assist settings menu, in VS2010 IDE)

but as for as Visual 2012, this is a fresh installation and have no visual assist, so what could be the reason....

this is what i have rit now[image]

this is what i was using in 2010 with same color scheme[image]

Comment: even for a different color scheme, it was the same problem....

Comment: Which *language* are you using? C++?

Comment: c#, by the way its not happening in just cs in other files as well

Comment: in above image, the colors of" userscontext : dbcontext "is not from custom color scheme...

Comment: It looks like the same color that is used for other user types. Have you checked the color settings in Options just to be certain?

Comment: @ cody, i have posted my previous experience with VS2k10

Comment: I don't know what that proves. I don't have it installed right now, but I'm pretty sure that VS 2012 added support for highlighting a bunch of additional syntax elements. If you don't want to check, that's fine.

Comment: ok is there a way to disable the highlighting from VS, as color scheme takes care of highlighting...